# how to make AJAX use POST and not GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I got this working code right here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    $('#response').hide();

    $('#addroom').click(function(){
        var url = "./scripts/addnew_room.php";

        var room_num = document.getElementById('rm_num').value;
        var room_type = document.getElementById('rm_type').value;
        var tosend = "&rm_num="+room_num+"&rm_type="+room_type;

        ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                var return_data = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = return_data;    
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.send(tosend);
        $('#response').show();
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = '<img src="./ajax-images/ajax-loader.gif">';
    });
});
```

can someone tell me why it is not sending the variable into POST method and even if i set up the method to POST it is still using a GET method and disrupts my page!!!

Comment: Eh.. as you are using jQuery, why don't you use jQuery ajax instead. It's much easier...

Comment: `$.ajax()` is your friend. No need to use `XMLHttpRequest` directly if you've already got jQuery.

Comment: What type of element is `#addroom`? If it's an `<a>`, you may need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) within the `.click()` handler.

Comment: is your button type "submit"?

Comment: I got it..it's a clinical error... but i'll take all that advise about using a jQuery..i put a <form> tag at the top and i forgot to put preventDefault(); so it mess me up..^_^..well thanks for your kindness :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this

```
$.POST("url.com", {name: "John", location: "Boston"}, function(){

})
```

[`POST()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is a  jquery function

You can also use jquery [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"url.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
}).done(function(data){
// this is very simple to get or post data
$("#response").html(data);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do it would be to just use jQuery's nifty [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#response').hide();

    $('#addroom').click(function() {
        $('<img />', {src: 'ajax-images/ajax-loader.gif'}).appendTo('#response');

        $.post({
            url: 'scripts/addnew_room.php',
            data: {
                rm_num: $('#rm_num').val(),
                rm_type: $('#rm_type').val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#response').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: my real problem is this "index.php?rm_num=223&rm_type=Standard+Double" it appends on the URL even if i make the method POST

Comment: This is a problem with your PHP or HTML code then. Sending a GET/POST request doesn't change the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this

```
ajax = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your_php_page.php",
    data: "a=1&b=2",
    success: function(msg){     
        //success handler
    },
    error: function(msg){
       //error handler
    }
});
```

Comment: my real problem is this "index.php?rm_num=223&rm_type=Standard+Double" it appends on the URL even if i make the method POST

Comment: to my knowledge if you use `POST` as the type it wont append it to the  url but your request have a seperate section called `Form Data` and the parameters will be listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test_form(){
    var cnt = $("#formid").serialize();
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url to your function',
    data: cnt,
    success: function(msg){
        //required code
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
dataValues = "a=1&b=2";
$.post("your_php_page.php", dataValues, function(data){

},"json");
```

//in your php file "your_php_page.php"

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
```

//you can also return data in json fomat in this way

```
$returnData = array();
echo json_encode($returnData);
```